# Github Profile in Search Engines

Tags: github, search-engine

Recently I changed my **github username** due to some issue. But google cannot re-index my new **github profile link**. There is any way to fix it ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Interesting! I've never searched my username after I make changes to it. Maybe it will automatically fix after minutes? Or hours?

Comment: are you face same issue ?

Comment: No, I think maybe it’s only because there’s a network delay?

Comment: Hi there, does the problem still exist?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I faced the same issue. Apparently, if you change your name from the profile tab(go to settings) google does not re-index it. However, if you go to the account tab(settings) and click `Change username` google will re-index your new profile link.

Comment: Weirdly it works!